# C++: Any reason why function returning pointer shouldn't be const?

Tags: c++

I wanted to know whether there's any reason a function returning a pointer shouldn't be const.  I'm working on some code that seems to be const-correct in most places, but for some reason doesn't declare functions returning pointers as const.  For example, it writes

```
virtual Joint* getJointByID(unsigned int id);
```

instead of

```
virtual Joint* getJointByID(unsigned int id) const;
```

If the getJointByID function itself in fact doesn't change any members of the class, is there any reason the const shouldn't be there?

Comment: Can you change the state of the object via the pointer?

Comment: Via the returned pointer, yes, but the function call itself will never alter any of the class' data members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This actually makes sense. If the function was to be declared with `const` it means it could be used on a constant instance (constvar.getJointByID...). But if it returns a pointer to an internal structure that could then be modified, it will allow the user to bypass the instance's const limit.

When not declared with `const` (like it is), you can't invoke the function on a const instance, and so the constness is preserved. If it had been declared `const`, it should better have returned a `const Joint*`.

(I'm assuming here that the Joint* is indeed part of the class data structure. If the class returns a newly allocated copy of some `Joint` or so, it's ok for it not to be constant. This depends on the implementation)

Comment: + 1.  A very good explanation of the reason why the code was designed this way.  And yes, the Joint is part of the class data, to be passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know whether there's any reason a function returning a
>   pointer shouldn't be const.

There is no such rule of thumb. `const`ness depends on what you are doing inside the function.

> If the getJointByID function itself in fact doesn't change any members
>   of the class, is there any reason the const shouldn't be there?

You are correct here. The function should have been `const` as part of good programming practice. However it's not mandatory.

Also, most of the times, derived classes follow same method patterns of base classes when they intend to override their `virtual` methods. Now, if the base class is legacy, then one cannot change its syntax by putting `const`; so same chain is followed for all derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

Const correctness doesn't solely depend on the return type; what you return from the method also matters.

If you are returning some data which is internal to the object, the `const` modifier on the method will not allow others to be able to modify this internal data. Even if you don't modify the object inside the method, you can't simply serve the internals to the outside world with mutation permission. This doesn't make sense when you call this method on a constant instantiation of your class.

Your best bet is to return your member data by protecting it with a pointer to constant:

```
virtual const Joint* getJointByID(unsigned int id) const;
```

Comment: I want to have the possibility of changing the state of the object via the returned pointer.  So...does that mean I should not declare the function as const?  Also, if I did return a const Joint*, it couldn't be dereferenced as an l-value but still could be dereferenced as an r-value?  Or does the const only apply to the pointer value and not to what the pointer points to?

Comment: @Gravity - Constant methods are methods that can be invoked from constant objects. If you want to change the internal state of an object, then it can't be a constant object, ergo you can't declare your method as constant. `const Joint*` means pointer to constant `Joint` object. It refers to the object and not to the pointer. But in either case you can't use the return value as an l-value. Primitive types (pointer in this case) as return types are immutable by language design. This is a special case unrelated to your problem here.

Comment: I meant the result of dereferencing such a pointer, not the pointer type itself.  That is, is it true that I can do (*returnedJoint) = something; only if returnedJoint is NOT marked with const?

Comment: @Gravity - If it is not a pointer to const, yes you can do this. That's why you are not allowed return it from a const method. You can cast away the constness, but you can modify your object through a pointer only if it is not marked as const, unless of course you do not override your objects memory area by pointer tricks. The compiler assumes that you will not do things like that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no relation between the type of the return value and the const-correction.

**But** if the pointer you return is in a structure that is part of the object, then you should return pointer to `const`, or not declare the function as `const` because you're able to change the object through that pointer.